# How to enable 3-finger drag in Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina

In Accessibility, I can't find any option for 3-finger drag in Trackpad settings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Accessibility > Pointer Control > Trackpad options > Check "Enable dragging" > Select 3 fingers drag from the drop down

Comment: To disable: mine was unchecked but 3 finger drag was still on, toggling it on and off fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Try to use spotlight(command+space)to search the Accessibility, and then you will see. You cannot get there from System preference >> Trackpad. Hope you find it helpful.